# Converting hana tables to hdb tables

Tags: hana

Can anyone help on how to convert hana sql tables to .hdb tables and use them? For converting into .hdb files at first I have imported table .csv format and after this I am not sure how to convert to .hdb table. can someone provide any process

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what you going for but using hdb tables is as easy as creating table_name.hdb in exactly the same format (I.E. COLUMN TABLE ... ) as it was created in "classic" schema. [Help Sap hdbtables](https://help.sap.com/viewer/4505d0bdaf4948449b7f7379d24d0f0d/2.0.03/en-US/453d48e28f6747799546236b4b432e58.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the SAP HANA developer CLI's [massConvert](https://github.com/SAP-samples/hana-developer-cli-tool-example#massconvert) functionality to convert one or more tables to hdbtable.

Note that this will only take care of the table structure. If you have data that you want to keep you will have to copy it manually, for example, via a CSV export/import.